# Spinner displays wrong value

Tags: android, spinner

I have a simple program where I set a spinner to a position.  I then call a second module and when I return, I reset the spinner.  The spinner display does not display the spinner value.  When you tap the spinner, it IS pointing to the correct value, but it displays an incorrect value.  In fact, it actually steps down.

I wrote the following simple program to demonstrate.  This only happens when the form has a spinner within either a Linearlayout or TableLayout with at lease 1 other element.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="Main Form" />

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget43" 
    android:layout_width="320dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn" android:text="Button" android:textSize="16sp"    
        android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="40dp" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/btnFour" android:textSize="16sp"    
        android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="40dp"    />
  </LinearLayout>       
</LinearLayout>
```

next.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/id1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java

```
package tt.zzz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class main extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
 {
     super.onCreate(icicle);     
     setContentView(R.layout.main);    
     fillSpinner();

     Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
  btnGo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) { Go(); } });
 }

 void Go() {
  Intent i = new Intent(this, next.class );
  startActivityForResult( i, 0 );
 }

 public void fillSpinner(){
  Spinner spin_test = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.btnFour );

  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> myAdapter =
   new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    );
  myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  

  myAdapter.add("Option 1" );
  myAdapter.add("Option 2" );
  myAdapter.add("Option 3" );

  spin_test.setAdapter(myAdapter);
  spin_test.setSelection(1);

  spin_test.setOnItemSelectedListener( 
                new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> 
                          arg0,View arg1,int arg2,long arg3){
    }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   }
  }); 
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  fillSpinner(); 
 }
}
```

next.java

```
package tt.zzz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class next extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After your setSelection, add the following line:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the same as barmaley suggested, except add the following:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  fillSpinner();
}
```

The reason why that's needed is because you launch another activity, so this one is paused.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    this.fillSpinner();
}
```

Since onCreate called only once, so to update Spinner each time you should refresh it somewhere else. onStart() - appropriate place for that

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it had no impact at all.  The displayed spinner value decrements down on every cycle, and the value popped up still shows the correct value, unlike the collapsed spinner.